# Apply a multi parameter function to all data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply, mapply

I have a list of data frames each with 3 columns.

```
list_of_df <- list(df1 = data.frame(f = c(6,4,2,9,7), g = c(7,5,3,1,8), h = c(4,2,1,3,6)),
                   df2 = data.frame(f = c(5,3,1,8), g = c(6,4,2,9), h = c(4,1,5,7)))
list_of_df
$df1
  f g h
1 6 7 4
2 4 5 2
3 2 3 1
4 9 1 3
5 7 8 6

$df2
  f g h
1 5 6 4
2 3 4 1
3 1 2 5
4 8 9 7
```

etc.

I have defined a function to calculate the area under the curve (auc):

`auc <- function(x,y) sum(diff(x) * (head(y,-1)+tail(y,-1)))/2`

For each data frame, column `f` is the input `x` and column `g` is the input `y`.

Now I want to use a version of `apply()` (not fussed which one) to apply the function `auc` to each data frame in the list. But I need to be able to specify that columns `f` and `g` should be used as the input.

So far, all my attempts to specify the columns have instead resulted in accidentally specifying a data frame from the list.

Any ideas how I might be able to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind using dput to make your example reproducible?  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I am pretty convinced that your function does not calculate AUC, as the output for your first data frame is -15. Are you sure that is what you want to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AUC function does not seem right to me, but the `sapply` function takes a list as an input.

```
auc <- function(x,y) sum(diff(x) * (head(y,-1)+tail(y,-1)))/2

list_of_df <- list(df1 = data.frame(f = c(6,4,2,9,7), g = c(7,5,3,1,8), h = c(4,2,1,3,6)),
                   df2 = data.frame(f = c(5,3,1,8), g = c(6,4,2,9), h = c(4,1,5,7)))
list_of_df
$df1
  f g h
1 6 7 4
2 4 5 2
3 2 3 1
4 9 1 3
5 7 8 6

$df2
  f g h
1 5 6 4
2 3 4 1
3 1 2 5
4 8 9 7

sapply(list_of_df, function(x) auc(x$f, x$g))
  df1   df2 
-15.0  22.5
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I've replaced my auc formula with the AUC function from DescTools, same number but prevents it from being negative.